# How to know what Task is Taskeng running?

Tags: windows

I've notice a couple of taskeng.exe instances running on my PC today. I know that these runs tasks scheduled in the task manager.

Question is: How to know, at run time, which specific task is running any given taskeng.exe instance?

Note: This happens just a couple of days after removing (manually) an adware (iminent), which may or not be related to the incident.

Comment: How would knowing the correlation between task and program instance help? If you want to know which task's currently running, unless you have a huge number scheduled, can't you simply check Task Scheduler?

Comment: Karan ...it would help to detect which task is causing problems (suchas as consuming too much memory or cpu time, or locking a file). And check the Task Scheduler does not help when the tasks have a long execution time.